# Can capacitor operate under voltage exceeding its "Maximum Working Voltage"?

Tags: capacitor

For example, I have a capacitor like this - https://aliexpress.com/item/32779085832.html. Its "Maximum Working Voltage" equal to 70V AC. Can I use this capacitor in 220V electrical circuit for 20 seconds without damaging capacitor?

Comment: How about "NO" ?

Comment: I'd expect it to go bang almost immediately in that situation. You need proper mains rated caps.

Comment: Slightly over - often MAY be OK. Factor of 3 - "Are you feeling lucky, punk?". Very low chance.

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether your board was damaged by mains connection? If so - what capacitors were switched in at the time. A capacitance meter (in many DMMs) will allow you to test capacitance of each capacitor. If none are burnt or interesting shapes or generally of a melted appearance you may have been lucky.

Comment: Dogs and electronics are usually not a good mix :-).

Comment: Hmm....dont try it .... :P

Answer (score 3):

A maximum rating isn't a promise the part will fail if the rating is exceeded, it's just a lack of promise the part won't fail.

However, some capacitors actually require de-rating below their nominal working voltage specs if they're used at any kind of elevated temperature or with significant ripple currents. And the ratings on parts from random Alibaba sellers are likely to be more optimistic than ones from established Western or Japanese manufacturers.

But even if these are high quality parts, operating them at more than 2x its rating is likely to lead to failure very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Do bear in mind that a typical 220V AC circuit is likely to be connected to the mains. The mains has spikes which can easily exceed 1500V, that's to be considered the lowest rated voltage of an ordinary capacitor that you want to connect to mains.

There are available specially rated capacitors, not much more expensive than ordinary ones, with [X and Y ratings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_types#Class_X_and_Class_Y_capacitors), which have a special construction to bounce back from these overvoltage events without 'failing dangerous'.